# Specifying the file type for upload using input element

Tags: html, angular, angular2-template

I'm trying to upload files but the problem is to specify the type of the file. I want the user to be able to choose only ".txt" files.

This is the html piece of code:

```
<input type="file" style="display:none;" (change)="upload($event)" accept=".txt" />
```

Unfortunately the "accept" attribute doesn't work as expected: you can still choose any file.

Any ideas what might cause the problem?

This is the angular function:

```
upload(event: EventTarget) {
    let eventObj: MSInputMethodContext = <MSInputMethodContext>event;
    let target: HTMLInputElement = <HTMLInputElement>eventObj.target;
    let fileList: FileList = target.files;

    if (fileList.length > 0) {
        let file: File = fileList[0];
        let formData: FormData = new FormData();
        formData.append('uploadFile', file, file.name);
        let headers = new Headers()
        let options = new RequestOptions({ headers: headers });

        this.http.post(this.transactionUrl, formData, options)
            .subscribe(
            (data) => {
                console.log('success');
            },
            (error) => {
                console.log('failure');
            });
    }        
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You just need to add the correct param to the accept attribute:

```
   <input type="file" 
     id="file" 
     name="file" 
     accept="text/plain">
```

It can be a list of formats separated by comma, see the [reference](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_accept.asp)

Example:

```
<input type="file" name="file" accept=
"application/msword, application/vnd.ms-excel, application/vnd.ms-powerpoint,
text/plain, application/pdf, image/*">
```